# Apache to NGINX Rewrite Issue

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm trying to convert this apache `ReWriteRule` to NGINX but it doesn't seem to be working.

Apache Rule: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.php$  index.php?pagename=$1 [NC,QSA]`

NGINX (not working): `location / { rewrite ^/([A-Za-Z0-9_-]+)\.php? /index.php?pagename=$1; }`

I do have the NGINX rule in a location block.

What am I missing here? I looked at the other similar questions but didn't find enough suitable clues to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's probably in the wrong `location` block. Is there a location block which handles any URI which ends with `.php`? The `rewrite` statement needs to be in the `location` block that is selected to process the original request, or alternatively, the `server` block.

Comment: I'll check that out and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using [converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.php$ /index.php?pagename=$1;
}
```

And indeed, many rewrites are easier with just a `rewrite` placed in the `server {}` context (no need for extraneous `location`).